# how to add frame numbers over footage in blender video editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, movie-clip-editor

simple noob question, how to add frames footage in blender video editor like the image below?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way to do that is to use the Animation Nodes addon to easily link a text strip of the VSE to a value.

[image]

- Once your video added to the VSE, add a text effect strip: <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, then 'effect strips' and 'text'
- Choose its colors, size, position, etc. on the <kbd>N</kbd>/right panel of the VSE

[image]

Now go to the Node Editor, choose Animation Nodes (see below for installation link) and add a new node tree.

Here is the node setup and information below on how to add the nodes: we'll do that in two steps as AN adds some nodes automatically

[image]

1 : choose add then 'animation' and 'time info'

2 : add 'sequence' and 'text sequence output' and select your text strip name

3 : connect 1 and 2 and this conversion node (3) will be added automatically

At this step, you have the frame displayed over the video. But it will be displayed with decimals.
So add an integer input to convert it, like in 4 below (add, then 'number' and 'integer')

[image]

Animation Nodes addon can be found here : https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/releases

Comment: I wonder if you can also call each strip's current time properties to display as well?

Comment: @3pointedit, yes I think that can be done (at least by converting frames to time by some calculations). There are *many* nodes and information to take from them (for instance a *sequence info* node as input). You can also use Python expressions, and add drivers or keyframes in the nodes themselves (I did not checked if there is a way to access fps directly, though).

Comment: Can AN see "any" current strips at the playhead position or do you have to define a "specific" strip as the node input?

Comment: @3pointedit, I am not an AN specialist (learn in progress), but concerning the VSE, there are 4 nodes for now : "time info", "get all sequences" (a list of all sequences), "sequence from channel" and "sequence info" (which gives name, type, channel, final duration, final start frame and final end frame)

Answer (score 5):

In the scene preferences turn ON metadata. Select the information that you would like to see in the frame. You can choose to see the scene properties but not the strip properties unfortunately*.

[image: Metadata on]

Here is the overlay in the render view, only available when a new frame is rendered.

[image: meta overlay]

Sorry it does not seem to be available in the VSE live view. You could keep a little UV Image editor window open and hit f12 occasionally.

*According to this code entry for the Metadata function https://developer.blender.org/D1592 you cannot access Sequence Strip information.