# How can i render a frame number in blender video editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor, keyframes, video

i wanted to show the number of the photographic sequence like this[image]

how can i do it in blender video editor? thank you!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73961/how-to-add-frame-numbers-over-footage-in-blender-video-editor?rq=1

Comment: @JohnEason There is no Blender version given in the question, presuming it's the current stable version - is the accepted linked answer still valid? Is there a working Animation Nodes addon for the latest Blender release?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann There are actually two answers on that page and the bottom one is more relevant to later Blender versions. I'll knock up an answer which should apply to all recent Blender versions.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: Animation nodes is working for all versions (since it came out at least) - but you may have to compile it yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to add frame numbers over footage in blender video editor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73961/how-to-add-frame-numbers-over-footage-in-blender-video-editor)

Comment: @JohnEason Yeah, but the second answer is a bit unsatisfying since it is just using the metadata over which you have not that much control.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I assume that's exactly what the original poster was asking for!

Comment: @JohnEason I assumed when the question says "like this" it should be looking more individual and maybe some option where to place the number.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I agree about the placement. In fact if you leave the default items selected and render a frame they end up in all four corners of the image! :^(

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: i know, that's why i voted to close the question because of duplication - and that's what the site does, if you vote it, it adds the comment. You should have known that...

Answer (score 3):

See the Blender [Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/output/properties/metadata.html#metadata) entry about Metadata. To add the Frame number to your rendered output, select the <kbd>Output Properties</kbd> icon in the R/H panel and scroll down to the <kbd>Metadata</kbd> section. You can then check only the information you want shown in the rendered output. Check <kbd>Burn into Image</kbd> and choose a suitable font size and colour. I'd suggest at least 24 px font size. The frame number is displayed in the bottom left corner of the output and as far as I can see there's no way of changing its position on the image.

[image]

This is the output when frame 7 is rendered

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would do it with *Geometry Nodes*. Just take any object like a plane for example and add a *Geometry Nodes* nodetree to it.

Then you take a *Scene Time* node and plug the *Frame* output into a *Value to String* node and that into a *String to Curve* node. There you can adjust all the settings for font, size, alignment etc. to your liking. Afterwards comes a *Fill Curve* node and a *Set Material* node.

Now you can put this object in front of the camera so that it is placed wherever you want it in the image. Parent it to the camera and it will stay there no matter how the camera moves. If you do not want the frame number to interact with anything in the scene, go to the *Object Properties* > *Visibility* > *Ray Visibility* and disable everything except for *Camera*.

The nodetree:

[image: GN setup]

And the result:

[image: animation]

Of course you can put anything in there, the frame number, the seconds, or calculate something based on frames or seconds and put that in there. You could even animate the frame number to be moving while the animation is running.